# ESP32: HttpClient.get() fails with -1

Tags: http, wifi, http-get, arduino-ide, esp32

I'm programming my ESP32 with the ArduinoIDE and have a problem with HTTP GET. What I'm doing:

- the ESP32 connects as WiFi client to an existing WiFi network using a static, fixed IP
- a webserver is started which provides a webpage for OTA firmware update -> this works, the webpage is accessible via the static IP
- using HttpClient I try to GET an other, remote webserver, but this fails

This is the code I'm using for the HTTP GET call:

```
static WiFiClient wifi;

HttpClient wlanHttp=HttpClient(wifi,"my.server.tld");
wlanHttp.get("/setpos.php?id=DEADBEEF"); // -> this fails with error code -1
wlanHttp.responseStatusCode(); // follow-up error -1
wlanHttp.stop();
```

Any idea what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

The confusing part here is the ESP32 has a built in http client called HTTPClient. The one for Arduino is called HttpClient and I'd like to find the guy who decided on that name and see if he's okay. HTTPClient has a routine called getString() that is a lovely way to gather info from a json api call, but HttpClient won't compile with that because it has no clue what that is.

Answer (score 0):

On ESp32 (if using the HTTPClient.h) the code should look like that:

```cpp
static WiFiClient wifi;
HttpClient wlanHttp;

wlanHttp.begin("http://my.server.tld/setpos.php?id=DEADBEEF"); //Specify the URL
int httpCode = wlanHttp.GET();                                 //Make the request

if (httpCode > 0) { //Check for the returning code
  if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) { 
    // get payload with http.getString();
    Serial.println(httpCode);
    // Serial.println(payload);
  } else {
    Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", wlanHttp.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
  }
} else {
  Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
}

wlanHttp.end(); //Free the resources
```

Comment: The code I use is valid - as I have two methods of sending HTTP-requests (one via WiFi, the other via GSM), I have to use these functions in order to specify  which communication stack has to be used.

Comment: Update: when using the aboves code, GET() returns -1 too

Comment: Please post all relevant code - you use IDE 1.8.12 and ESP32 core 1.04? There is something else fishy. Try to test isolated parts first.

Comment: I'm getting a bit closer: the AP my ESP32 is connecting to did not provide DNS information properly. Now that I'm setting it via WiFi.config() explicitly, I made some progress: wlanHttp.get() returns 0 now but wlanHttp.responseStatusCode() now issues a -3